# Change user-type name of Active-X plug-in written in C#

Tags: c#, user-controls, activex, ole

I'm currently appointed the task of creating an Active-X plug-in for one of our clients. Now I've successfully created Active-X plug-in in C#/.NET (a Windows Form control which inherits from the `System.Windows.Forms.UserControl` class), however the application that hosts the plug-in shows the class name of the control in the caption of the dialog window that displays the Active-X plug-in.

After a lot of searching and disassembling I've found that the method `IOleObject.GetUserType` is called by the host and that it is the return value of this method that is used by the host as the caption of the dialog window. Looking at the `System.Windows.Forms.UserControl` class I found that this class inherits from the `System.Windows.Forms.Control` class which in turn explicitly implements the `System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IOleObject` interface.

What I would like to know is if there is someway to override the `GetUserType` method 
in the `UserControl` class or if there is another way to accomplish what I want (maybe the solution is very simple, but I've failed to see it so far). I've already tried various 'possible' solutions so far:

1. I've tried to re-implement the `IOleObject` interface, but since the `System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IOleObject` is internal it is not possible to do this (you must use the exact same interface, and redefining an interface does not result in the exact same interface).
2. I've tried to use CLR injection as described by Ziad Elmalki on [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/CLRMethodInjection.aspx).
3. I've tried to use some form of AOP. Since the `Control` class inherits from `System.MarshalByRefObject` through `System.ComponentModel.Component` I thought it might be possible to get my user control to return some kind of proxy that would intercept calls send to the `GetUserType` method.

Unfortunately I've not been able to get this to work. What does work is changing the name of the class, but since class names are not allowed to have spaces or other special characters this is not an acceptable solution (underscores are just not the same).

To elaborate, here's a code example of what I want to accomplish (note that it's not complete):

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;

[ ComVisible(true)
, ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDual)
, Description("My Active-X plug-in")
, Guid("...")
]
public partial class MyControl : UserControl
{
    public override int GetUserType(int dwFromOfType, out string userType)
    {
        userType = "The caption to show in the host";
        // Return S_OK
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Hopefully someone here could help me.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You could attempt to implement ICustomQueryInterface (.Net 4.0): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.icustomqueryinterface.aspx

When the system queries for IOleObject, you could return your own custom object that implements IOleObject, forwards the methods you don't care about to the UserControl implementation, and properly delegate QueryInterface calls on the custom object back to the UserControl (aggregation).

Comment: Although I was able to implement the ICustomQueryInterface and return my own implementation of the IOleObject interface, forwarding the methods I don't care about to the UserControl is not something trivial. The problem remains the same: some interfaces/structs used by the IOleObject implementation provided by the Control class are private/internal and cannot be used, so you have to duplicate those interfaces/structs somehow and get them to be converted to the internal implementation used by the Control class (which is not possible as far as I can tell).

Comment: I was hoping that the IOleObject and corresponding interfaces and structs provided in the Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop assembly are somehow compatible with the IOleObject provided in System.Windows.Forms assembly, but this is not the case... unfortunately!