# Best Practice for disable automatically deactivating .NET ActiveX Controls in VB6?

Tags: c#-4.0, com, vb6, activex, vb6-migration

I'm porting an old Visual Basic 6 program. I deployed the migrated component in WPF and provide that component as an ActiveX control (C#, Windows Forms, .NET Framework) to add the control temporarily (to break the porting process into smaller parts) in the VB6 application.

This works great if the external ActiveX control is added in VB6 to the whole form like

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    Set mCtrl = Controls.Add("ActiveX_Control.UserControl1", "UserControl1", Me)
    Set mActiveX = mCtrl.object
    mCtrl.Visible = True
End Sub
```

But if I add the control to a container (Picture1 = picture box), the control will be automatically deactivate (if the .NET control loose the focus):

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    Set mCtrl = Controls.Add("ActiveX_Control.UserControl1", "UserControl1", Picture1)
    Set mActiveX = mCtrl.object
    mCtrl.Visible = True
End Sub
```

I learned that the interface IOleInPlaceObject is responsible for this behaviour. Also about the C# interface [ICustomQueryInterface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6276584/change-user-type-name-of-active-x-plug-in-written-in-c-sharp).
Therefore I suppress the interface at runtime with this knowledge:

```
public CustomQueryInterfaceResult GetInterface(ref Guid iid, out IntPtr ppv)
{
    if (iid == typeof(IOleInPlaceObject).GUID)
    {
        ppv = IntPtr.Zero;
        return CustomQueryInterfaceResult.Failed;
    }
    ppv = IntPtr.Zero;
    return CustomQueryInterfaceResult.NotHandled;
}
```

This seems to work, but the new problem is that now the ActiveX control doesn't got automatically the focus if pressing TAB key (last control in VB6 before the ActiveX control).

Is that even the right way?
Is there a better way? Maybe via a different return value from IOleObject::GetMiscStatus of the ActiveX control?

The sample C# and VB6 project you can download [here](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/wh7o87w940smcgbnhbcnu/Sample.zip?rlkey=45res89de9dx1814izyzvppf2&dl=0).

Comment: For me the problem is exactly the same in both case: as soon as focus leaves the .NET control, it's Visible property is set to False because it's deactivated for some internal VB reason (it's like the .NET control is not enabled/focusable). You can override SetVisibleCore and do nothing when value is false, you can reset Visible when it's changed to false, etc. You can also implement IOleInPlaceObject and do nothing when InPlaceDeactivate and UIDeactivate are called. But it won't automatically refocus on the .NET control using keyboard. It should work with mouse though.

Comment: @SimonMourier I don't think it's vb's fault. In debugger you can see, that the interface IOleInPlaceObject is called from .NET! In principle, calling InPlaceDeactivate and UIDeactivate is correct if the interface exists. But the problem is that this interface is automatically added by .NET.
Interestingly, the problem does not exist if the .NET control is used directly in a Windows Forms. I think the COM interface is ignored here.

Comment: It's not ignored. If you implement it, you can see it's used (by VB OLE site implementation). If you put a breakpoint when OnVisibleChanged is called with false, you can see the stack trace the original cause is VB calling deactivate when a TAB passes through IOleInPlaceActiveObject.TranslateAccelerator. If you follow OnGotFocus/OnLostFocus you'll see .NET control never gets the focus. .NET is now open source, VB6 is not, I can't be 100% conclusive about whose fault it is I don't see why VB deactivates the control.

Comment: I strongly suggest rewriting the TITLE of this question so it corresponds to the core of what is actually being asked. Nothing in it right now conveys any specifically useful information. The tags cover the tech stack in use.

Comment: Is there a particular reason this is tagged c#-4.0? I don't think the question explains this.